# Suddenly lost all contacts and calendar entries

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, calendar

My iPhone just lost all of my contacts and calendar entries, except for 5 contacts that I haven't used in years and actually deleted a few months ago.  It also lost my saved player info for at least one game (Infinity Blade II).

I didn't change anything or do anything to my phone; it just suddenly doesn't have any of this information.  I still have all my apps, most of which seem to be fine, and I still have my recent calls information, but there are no names associated with the numbers.

What could have caused this and how can I get everything back?

**EDIT:** I tried restarting my phone. That didn't seem to help. But, here it is, 15 minutes later, and almost everything is back. I'm still missing a couple of contacts and my game profile.

**EDIT 2:** What I would still like to figure out is ***what happened***. The answers are all focused on backup & restore options. None of them addresses what might have gone wrong or how I can prevent this from happening again in the future, which is the real point of this question.

Comment: are you syncing ?

Comment: No. I wasn't doing anything.

Comment: Do you use iCloud ?

Comment: Yes. My phone prompted me to sign into iCloud a few minutes before this happened. I hit cancel, although it still says I'm signed in.

Comment: ......................... :)

Answer (score 1):

Recommend you do this

iOS: Back up and restore your iOS device with iCloud or iTunes

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1766

Here is also very nice [step by step](http://iphone-contacts.over-blog.com/article-iphone-contacts-disappear-106829462.html).

Comment: I'm hesitant to do a restore when (1) I don't know what happened, (2) almost everything seems to be back, and (3) I'm not confident my phone has actually been backing up correctly.

Answer (score -4):

i just backed up manually and everything came back..

Comment: This answer doesn't provide enough details -- you'll find it's going to attract a lot of downvotes as a result. How did you back up manually? Do you really mean "backed up" or do you mean "restored from a previous backup"?